# insertion of values in 2D array in pl-sql

Tags: plsql

i am new and trying to learn pl sql programming.

How can we insert data in 2D array using plsql program. i was able to insert data in 1D array, but i am facing problems for inserting data in 2D array.

```
declare
  type type1 is table of number;
  type data_type is table of type1;
  y data_type;
begin
  y := data_type();
  y.extend(20000);
  for i in 1..100 loop
    for j in 1..100 loop
      y(i)(j) := i+j; 
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

any information or hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize and extend the outer array `y`, but you also need to initialize and extend each sub-array `y(i)`:

```
declare
  type type1 is table of number;
  type data_type is table of type1;
  y data_type;
begin
  y := data_type();
  y.extend(100);
  for i in 1..100 loop
    y(i) := type1();
    y(i).extend(100);
    for j in 1..100 loop
      y(i)(j) := i+j; 
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The above code runs successfully on my Oracle XE 11gR2 database.